# Is correct onclick method always call ngOnInit method?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have the fllowing html page with Angular:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade"
       *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <div class="button-row">
    <a mat-flat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/products']"><mat-icon>list</mat-icon></a>
  </div>
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title><h2>{{product.prod_name}}</h2></mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{product.prod_desc}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <dl>
        <dt>Product Price:</dt>
        <dd>{{product.prod_price}}</dd>
        <dt>Updated At:</dt>
        <dd>{{product.updated_at | date}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <a mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="editProduct()"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></a>
      <a mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></a>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And its corresponding component class:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import {Product} from '../product';
import {ViewProductService} from '../view-product.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-detail',
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.sass']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  product = {} as Product;
  product2 = {} as Product;
  subscription: Subscription;
  isLoadingResults = true;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private api: ApiService, private router: Router, private viewProductService: ViewProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.viewProductService.getCurrentProduct().subscribe(value => {
      this.product.id = String(value['_id']);
      this.product.prod_name = value.prod_name;
      this.product.prod_desc = value.prod_desc;
      this.product.prod_price = value.prod_price;
    });
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
    // this.getProductDetails(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }

  getProductDetails(id) {
    this.api.getProduct(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data;
        this.product.id = id;
        console.log(this.product);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }

  editProduct() {
    this.viewProductService.viewProduct(this.product);
    this.router.navigate(['/product-edit']);
  }

  deleteProduct(id) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.deleteProduct(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.router.navigate(['/products']);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

I'm new in Angular and this maybe will be a newbie wuestion. My problem is when onclick event is invoked, `ngOnInit` method is always called before `editProduct` method.

It's correct? It's a un unexpected beahvior for me. I don't need invoke `ngOnInit` method again because It renders page again and I don't need that.

Exist a way ngOnInit won't be called every time editProduct method is called?

Comment: onInit runs once and only once in a component's lifes cycle.  in your case, onInit is running because you navigate in your editProduct method.  So whatever component you're navigating to is running it's onInit method. that's how onInit works... it runs once as a component is initialized, and navigating initializes a new component

Comment: what is your error please add it in the question and is page refreshing when you click on edit product

Comment: @Supercool I means It's an unexpected beahvior for me.

Comment: @bryan60 exist a way for avoiding that? I don't need call onNgInit method because it invoke sentences which only will be invoked the first time

Comment: If you’re reloading a component, then you will invoke onOnit. Don’t reload the component by navigating.

Comment: I don't reload the component. After the component is loaded,  the first interaction that I make is the invocation of onclick event (editProduct method). This invocation generates a reloading of the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are routing to Product Detail Component each time when the user does click in the edit button, is that right? 
if this is correct, the behavior is expected because OnInit is one interface, among others which are included in the life cycle of the angular components.
You can see more here.
https://dzone.com/articles/angular-6-part-3-life-cycle-of-a-component

Pay attention that the ngOnInit method is in Detail Component not in the List Component, probably you have copied and pasted your code and lack doing changes edit method in the component in order to save the item changes instead of routing to the same item again.

Comment: This is the roue of my componentes: `ListProductComponent -> ProductDetailComponent -> ProductEditComponent.` Acoording to your comment. I understand I every time I make a click I will call ngOnInit method of ProductDetailComponent, right?